# Azure Function: Unable to read data from the transport connection : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am using Service Bus Topic trigger azure function, and this function is basically performing below tasks:

1. Calling external API(Janrain).
2. After that it is again calling external API(Mailjet) to trigger email.
3. Then it is publishing message into Service Bus Topic.

In the Azure Application insights I can see there are lot of `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` logged.

[image]

Exception details:

> ExceptionMessage:The SSL connection could not be established, see
> inner exception., StackTrace:   at
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream
> stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask,
> HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean
> disposeCts)    at
> Mailjet.Client.MailjetClient.PostAsync(MailjetRequest request)

Could you please suggest how can I fix this issue?

Below is my Janrain API client:

```
public class JanrainApiClient : IJanrainApiClient
    {
        #region private fields
        private readonly ILogger<JanrainApiClient> _logger;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly JanrainConfigOption _janrainConfigOption;
        #endregion

        #region ctors
        public JanrainApiClient(ILogger<JanrainApiClient> logger,
            IOptions<JanrainConfigOption> janrainConfigOption,
            IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            this._logger = logger;
            this._janrainConfigOption = janrainConfigOption.Value;
            this._httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        #endregion

        #region public methods
       
        public async Task<JanrainResultDto> FindAsync(string userUUID)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("{class} -> {method} -> Start",
                  nameof(JanrainApiClient), nameof(JanrainApiClient.FindAsync));

                JanrainResultDto resultDto = new JanrainResultDto();

                var request = GetJanrainApiRequest(userUUID);

                var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(GetServiceUrl(request));

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(_janrainConfigOption.Scheme, _janrainConfigOption.ApiAuth);

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(GetServiceUrl(request));

                var jsonAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JanrainApiResponse entityFindResponse = jsonAsString.AsPoco<JanrainApiResponse>();

                if (entityFindResponse != null && entityFindResponse.Results != null)
                {
                    resultDto = entityFindResponse.Results.FirstOrDefault();
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Error while requesting Janrain info for UserUUId:{userUUID}." +
                        $"Error:{entityFindResponse?.Error}, ErrorMessage:{entityFindResponse?.ErrorDescription}");
                }

                _logger.LogInformation("{class} -> {method} -> End",
                 nameof(JanrainApiClient), nameof(JanrainApiClient.FindAsync));

                return resultDto;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Exception while calling Janrain entity Find API for UserUUId :{userUUID}, " +
                    $"Error message:{ex.Message}, StackTrace:{ex.StackTrace}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region private methods
       
        private JanrainApiRequest GetJanrainApiRequest(string userUUId)
        {
            return new JanrainApiRequest
            {
                Username = string.Empty,
                TypeName = _janrainConfigOption.TypeName,
                Attributes = JanrainResultDto.Attributes(),
                QueryFilter = $"uuid='{userUUId}'",
                ClientId = _janrainConfigOption.ClientId,
            };
        }

      
        private string GetServiceUrl(JanrainApiRequest request)
        {
            return $"{_janrainConfigOption.EntityFindApiUrl}{request.ToQueryString()}";
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

Below is my Mailjet client factory:

```
public class MailjetClientFactory : IMailjetClientFactory
    {
        #region private fields
        private readonly MailjetConfigOption _mailjetConfigOption;
        #endregion

        #region ctors
        public MailjetClientFactory(IOptions<MailjetConfigOption> mailjetConfigOption)
        {
            _mailjetConfigOption = mailjetConfigOption.Value;
        }
        #endregion

        #region public methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Create Mailjet client
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The IMailjetClient instance.</returns>
        public IMailjetClient CreateClient()
        {
            return new MailjetClient(_mailjetConfigOption.PublicKey,
                _mailjetConfigOption.SecretKey)
            {
                Version = ApiVersion.V3_1
            };
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Sending email with Mailjet API:

```
public async Task<MailjetResponse> SendEmail(MailjetEmailMessage emailMessage)
        {
            var mailJetMessage = buildMailJetMessages.BuildMailjetMessageFor(emailMessage);

            var mailJetClient = createMailJetClients.CreateClient();

            var mailJetResponse = await mailJetClient.PostAsync(new MailjetRequest
            {
                Resource = Send.Resource,
            }.Property(Send.Messages, mailJetMessage));

            return mailJetResponse;
        }
```

Service Bus Message Factory:

```
public class AzureServiceBusFactory : IMessageBusFactory
    {
        #region private fields
        private readonly ServiceBusConfigOption _serviceBusConfigOption;
        private readonly object _lockObject = new object();
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusClient> _clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusClient>();
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusSender> _senders = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusSender>();
        
        #endregion

        public AzureServiceBusFactory(IOptions<ServiceBusConfigOption> serviceBusConfigOption)
        {
            _serviceBusConfigOption = serviceBusConfigOption.Value;
        }

        #region public methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Get ServiceBusClient
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="senderName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IMessageBus GetClient(string senderName)
        {
            var connectionString = _serviceBusConfigOption.ConnectionString;

            var key = $"{connectionString}-{senderName}";

            if (this._senders.ContainsKey(key) && !this._senders[key].IsClosed)
            {
                return AzureServiceBus.Create(this._senders[key]);
            }

            var client = this.GetServiceBusClient(connectionString);

            lock (this._lockObject)
            {
                if (this._senders.ContainsKey(key) && this._senders[key].IsClosed)
                {
                    if (this._senders[key].IsClosed)
                    {
                        this._senders[key].DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    }

                    return AzureServiceBus.Create(this._senders[key]);
                }

                var sender = client.CreateSender(senderName);

                this._senders[key] = sender;
            }

            return AzureServiceBus.Create(this._senders[key]);
        }
        #endregion

        #region protected methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Create ServiceBusClient
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected virtual ServiceBusClient GetServiceBusClient(string connectionString)
        {
            var key = $"{connectionString}";

            lock (this._lockObject)
            {
                if (this.ClientDoesnotExistOrIsClosed(connectionString))
                {
                    var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions
                    {
                        TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpTcp
                    });

                    this._clients[key] = client;
                }

                return this._clients[key];
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region private methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Check ClientDoesnotExistOrIsClosed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool ClientDoesnotExistOrIsClosed(string connectionString)
        {
            return !this._clients.ContainsKey(connectionString) || this._clients[connectionString].IsClosed;
        }
        #endregion

    }

internal class AzureServiceBus : IMessageBus
    {
        #region private fields
        private const string ContentType = "application/json";
        private readonly ServiceBusSender _serviceBusSender;
        #endregion

        #region ctors
        internal AzureServiceBus(ServiceBusSender serviceBusSender)
        {
            this._serviceBusSender = serviceBusSender;
        }
        #endregion

        #region public methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Publish message into Service Bus Topic 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task PublishMessageAsync<T>(T message, string messageId)
        {
            var serviceBusMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.AsJson()))
            {
                ContentType = ContentType
            };
            serviceBusMessage.MessageId = messageId;
            await this._serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Publish message into Service Bus Topic 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <param name="messageId"></param>
        /// <param name="filterPropertyName"></param>
        /// <param name="filterPropertyValue"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task PublishMessageAsync<T>(T message, string messageId, string filterPropertyName, string filterPropertyValue)
        {
            var serviceBusMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.AsJson()))
            {
                ContentType = ContentType
            };
            serviceBusMessage.MessageId = messageId;
            serviceBusMessage.ApplicationProperties.Add(filterPropertyName, filterPropertyValue);
            serviceBusMessage.CorrelationId = filterPropertyValue;

            await this._serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage);
        }
        #endregion

        #region internal methods
        internal static IMessageBus Create(ServiceBusSender sender)
        {
            return new AzureServiceBus(sender);
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

DI registrations:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJanrainApiClient, JanrainApiClient>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMailjetClientFactory, MailjetClientFactory>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageBusFactory, AzureServiceBusFactory>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMailjetEmailService, MailjetEmailService>();
```

Comment: When I see these in my socket app, it’s usually because of a bug in  the code. Can you add the full exception message, including any inner exceptions to your question (as text please, not an image)

Comment: @stuartd, I have added inner exception details.

Comment: Service Bus doesn't come into play here; if it was unable to connect, your Function would never be invoked.  The stack trace indicates that the failure is from the Mail Jet call.

Comment: @JesseSquire, Is there anything wrong, the way I am calling Mailjet APIs?

Comment: There's nothing that seems obvious from the general C# perspective that I see.    I have no insight into MailJet's SDK nor service endpoints.   Reaching out to their support for assistance may be the best path forward.